# Determine whether input-output pairs represent something that could be a proper math function

Tags: programming-challenge, haskell, functional-programming

> The input is read in line by line from stdin.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer, T, denoting the number of test
>   cases. The subsequent lines describe T test cases, and the input for
>   each test case is as follows:
>
> The first line contains an integer, N, the number of (x,y) pairs in
>   the test case. The N subsequent lines each contain two space-separated
>   integers describing the respective x and y values for each ordered
>   pair.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$1 \le T \le 5\$
> - \$2 \le N \le 100\$
> - \$0 \le x, y \le 500\$
>
> x and y are both integers.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> On a new line for each test case, print  if the set of ordered
>   pairs represent a valid function, or  if they do not.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 2  
> 3  
> 1 1  
> 2 2  
> 3 3  
> 4  
> 1 2  
> 2 4  
> 3 6  
> 4 8
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> YES   
> YES
> ```

[Full problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/lambda-calculi-march-2016/challenges/functions-or-not)

I'm looking for feedback regarding ways this could be: more concise/clean, more idiomatic Haskell, or if there are algorithmic/mathematical tricks I missed that could further simplify the computation.

```hs
import System.IO (readLn, getLine)
import Control.Monad (replicateM, mapM_, liftM)
import Data.List (nub)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M

data YesNo = YES | NO deriving Show

boolToYesNo :: Bool -> YesNo
boolToYesNo x = if x then YES else NO

readInt :: IO Int
readInt = readLn

tuplefy :: [a] -> (a, a)
tuplefy xs = case xs of [a, b] -> (a, b)
                        _      -> error "each item must consist of 2 values."

readPair :: [String] -> [(Int, Int)]
readPair = map $ tuplefy . map (read :: String -> Int) . words

getPairs :: Int -> IO [String]
getPairs = flip replicateM getLine

readTestCase :: Int -> IO [(Int, Int)]
readTestCase = fmap readPair . getPairs

readTestCases :: Int -> IO [[(Int, Int)]]
readTestCases = flip replicateM $ readInt >>= readTestCase

printAnswers :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
printAnswers = mapM_ print

isSingletonSet :: Eq b => [b] -> Bool
isSingletonSet xs = case nub xs of [x] -> True
                                   _   -> False

listToMultiMap :: (Ord k, Eq k, Eq v) => [(k, v)] -> M.Map k [v]
listToMultiMap ((k, v):vs) = toMap (M.fromList [(k, [v])]) vs
    where toMap m xs = case xs of []        -> m
                                  (k0, v0):ys ->
                                      case M.lookup k0 m of Nothing -> toMap (M.insert k0 [v0] m) ys
                                                            Just v0s -> toMap (M.insert k0 (v0:v0s) m) ys

functionOrNot :: [(Int, Int)] -> YesNo
functionOrNot tuples = boolToYesNo $ foldl1 (&&) $ M.elems $ M.map isSingletonSet $ listToMultiMap tuples

main :: IO ()
main = getAnswers >>= printAnswers
    where getAnswers = (liftM . map) functionOrNot $ readInt >>= readTestCases
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your monadic helper functions are all one-offs and even if they were well-named (no worries, naming just gets harder as you get more experienced, there's a reason Adam was told to do it), I'd still think it better to inline them. Then the main ends up cluttered with pointfreed binds and I turned that into a do block.

(I did reorder the monadic effects a little, moving the output of each answer in front of the reading of the next question, but I found that sacrifice worthy.)

I'm not sure you need to try your hand at error-handling in `tuplefy` - a badly formated input file should be as likely to have a typo in its number of words in a line as in its stated number of pairs in a function.

`listToMultiMap` - `(k, v)` is no different from the other elements of `vs`, so you could go `listToMultiMap = toMap M.empty`. `toMap` is folding left, bad style. You can fold right like:

```
toMap [] = []
toMap ((k0, v0):ys) = case M.lookup k0 m of
  Nothing  -> M.insert k0 [v0]     $ toMap ys
  Just v0s -> M.insert k0 (v0:v0s) $ toMap ys
```

and won't need to carry a parameter into the recursive calls. And of course this can be written in terms of foldr:

```
listToMultiMap = foldr foo M.empty where
  foo (k0, v0) m = case M.lookup k0 m of
    Nothing  -> M.insert k0 [v0]     m
    Just v0s -> M.insert k0 (v0:v0s) m
```

And we could reduce the duplication in the last two lines there, but then again this whole thing is already handled by `Data.Map`s `fromListWith`.

```
import System.IO (readLn, getLine)
import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.Bool (bool)

noDuplicates :: Ord a => [a] -> Bool
noDuplicates = all (==1) . M.fromListWith (+) . map (,1)
--           = all ((==1) . length) . M.fromListWith (++) . map (,["Why are you looking at the ordinate?"])
--           = and . M.fromListWith (\_ _ -> False) . map (,True)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  functioncount <- readLn
  replicateM functioncount $ do
    paircount <- readLn
    abscissae <- replicateM paircount $ read . head . words <$> getLine
    putStrLn $ bool "NO" "YES" $ noDuplicates abscissae
```

It is unfortunate for pointfreedom that the first parameter of replicateM indeed should be Int.  There must be a better way than flip. Perhaps a new infix operator, semantically id, that has highest precedence to the left, and lowest to the right, to simulate enclosing brackets around its entire right side and disappearing?

Comment: Wow, much simpler.  I would still make a small modification and use the `nub` function before passing the list to `map (,1)` to handle the case where the test cases might test the same input twice but get back the same result. For instance, the set [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 1)] is still a valid function because both times I got back the same value when the input '1' was tested.

Comment: If getting the same point twice is actually a thing that can happen (from the task description I would have assumed not), okay, but nub is quadratic time, and if you don't care about that, then `noDuplicates` can be replaced with `on (==) length =<< nub` without involving `Data.Map` at all.

If you do care, something like the first commentline variant of noDuplicates can be used to collect the actual ordinates, and then you check *those* per abscissa with e.g. `(== (1:Natural)) . genericLength.`

Answer (score 0):

In several places you can substitute `case ... of` with pattern matching to make the code a little more clear. One such place is the `tuplefy` function:

```
tuplefy :: [a] -> (a, a)
tuplefy [a, b] = (a, b)
tuplefy _      = error "each item must consist of 2 values."
```